# Mysql insert trigger doesn't work

Tags: mysql, triggers

Can you help me in the following:
There is a mistake when I'm trying to create the following trigger in Mysql 5.5
The trigger is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bookTakenDate  
AFTER INSERT ON readers_books  
for each row  
begin  
    update readers_books  
    set date_supposed_taken = new.date_given  
    where given_book_id = new.given_book_id;  
end;
```

The error is the following:

> SQL(1064): There is an error in SQL syntax; at line 1.

The structure of the table is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS readers_books (
    GIVEN_BOOK_ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    books_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    readers_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    date_given date DEFAULT NULL,
    date_supposed_taken date DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (GIVEN_BOOK_ID),
    KEY books_ID (books_ID),
    KEY readers_ID (readers_ID),
    CONSTRAINT readers_books_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (books_ID) REFERENCES BOOKS (ID),
    CONSTRAINT readers_books_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (readers_ID) REFERENCES READERS (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Actually the trigger should do the folloiwing. It should insert the +7 days in auto way into date_supposed_taken column

Answer (score 0):

Reffering to the docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html it looks like that "CREATE OR REPLACE" syntax is not supported.

It should work

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER bookTakenDate
AFTER INSERT ON readers_books
for each row
begin
update readers_books
set date_supposed_taken = new.date_given
where given_book_id = new.given_book_id;
end;//
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define different delimiter, and `DROP TRIGGER` before the `CREATE` instead of `CREATE OR REPLACE` which doesn't work.

```
DELIMITER $$ -- change delimiter

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `bookTakenDate`$$

CREATE TRIGGER bookTakenDate
AFTER INSERT ON readers_books
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE readers_books
    SET date_supposed_taken = new.date_given
    WHERE given_book_id = new.given_book_id;

END;$$

DELIMITER ; -- set original delimiter
```